# Time to Meet a Milestone

Tags: training

I am interested in understanding if measuring the time it takes for an adult to meet a training milestone is a training metric that is commonly used to assess progress and, if so, what adult learning theories or academics discuss this concept.

I would suspect that, during training, a group of adults would hit a particular milestone in a given range with some type of frequency distribution that would indicate normal.  I would further suspect that, as we approach either tail, there would be signs of something else going on that is either enhancing training or disabling it in some way and would be cause of alarm, where some type of training intervention would be required for the benefit of the student.

Conversely, is there any reasons why time to milestone is NOT important and should be ignored?  If so, what academic studies are behind that opinion?

EDIT:  I may have thought the topics of this exchange were a bit different, but my problem may generalize to those studying in academia.  Here's the specific question I have:

A debate is going on regarding the number of hours it takes for a pilot candidate to solo.  One side is arguing it simply does not matter, that it indicates nothing as far as the training is concerned or anything about the skills of the pilot after license.  The other side is arguing that it does matter because it indicates the health and progress of the training.  If you captured this solo metric across the US, you'd likely see a distribution of hours from something as low as 15 hours to maybe as high as 30 with the MODE somewhere around 20.  The latter group is arguing that, if your student is approaching 30, or even passes it, something's wrong in the training environment that needs changed.  It is a special cause variation versus normal or common cause variation.

I was hoping there was some literature that either supported or discounted the need to track time as part of an assessment in education or training.

Is this on topic for this group?  If not, please let me know so I can post in a more suitable group.  I was going to post in the Aviation exchange, but I don't think that is suitable because I am looking for more of an academic opinion.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean adults *in academia* -- e.g. graduate students?  If not, could you clarify why your question is on-topic for this site?  Just asking for "academic studies" is not enough: this site is for questions *about academia itself*, not which call for academic knowledge on various subjects.

Comment: I edited my comment but I'm not sure if it is considered on topic for this exchange.  Thanks for your consideration!

Comment: I feel the question is off-topic: it is not related to academia in itself. Probably the question is better suited to [Workplace.se](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: It is possibly a little ironic that a question relating to pedagogy (how adults learn) is off topic on a site for academics.

Comment: I voted to re-open because I think this question is on-topic. For example, what is meant by taking a 6 credit hour course? How much am I supposed to know after completing a 4 credit hour course instead of 6 credit? Why a course is designed that students must go to class 3 hours every week? Sorry about voting to close in the first place.

Comment: I think the example might be throwing people—I know it threw me at first. But I agree this is on-topic, if a bit off the main path.

Comment: Although [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5MgBikgcWnY) is a TedX talk, it throws some light on "metrics" such as how long it takes for someone to be "perfect" in a field.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it is in no way specific to academic learning. It **may** be on-topic on [cogsci.se].

Comment: I voted this question up because I think it is valid to ask if there is a general guide to the amount of time to meet academic milestones. Should general rules be applied, or should each case be treated differently? But I think the question needs to be modified to fit this interpretation. Perhaps you can ask a more general question on here, then an aviation specific question on Aviation exchange.

Comment: @scaaahu, as far as I know credits have nothing to do with what learners know, but to do with how much time is spent studying, either contact time with a staff member, or self-studying. Hence why a course can be failed, regardless of the amount of time a student has spent studying for the course. Learning outcomes are not reflected in the credit scoring of a course.

Comment: @David Espina, did you try the Mathematics Educators site with the same question?

Comment: @G-E _Learning outcomes are not reflected in the credit scoring of a course_? I fail to understand this. A course of 4 credits of grade A is definitely different from a course of 1 credit of grade A when calculating GPA.

Comment: @scaaahu, totally agreed about "definite difference" but on what ground is each credit given to a course (be it 1 or 4 credit(s))? Of course the learning outcomes will be different. But are learning outcomes the technical basis for the difference of credit amount? Locally, as far as I know, a credit is a reflection of the amount of study work spent, for instance a 20-credit course will require in the region of 120 hours of study time. So there is a milestone there. The educator thinks the learning outcomes for the course are achievable after 120 hours. Maybe it's different in diff. countries.

Comment: @G-E I am using US GPA system. Please see [GPA Calculator](http://gpacalculator.net/how-to-calculate-gpa/) In US, 4 credits means students and the professor(teacher)  meet 4 hours a week. You can translate number of hours in total if you want. To me, if I take two courses A and B. I must meet course A instructor total 20 hours and course B instructor 200 hours in total to get grade. Let's say I get A from both courses. Then I would assume I learn a lot more from course B because I spend 200 hours for B. That is what I mean.

Comment: @scaaahu, thanks for the link. I think we agree. The learning involved is 'assumed'. The unit that is technically used to decide on the amount of credits is study time, not the 'quantity' of learning, which can only be assumed in relation to the amount of study time/credits attached to the course. So, back to your original question, 'How much am I supposed to know after completing a 4 credit hour course instead of 6 credit?' and to the main question, there is no straightforward unambiguous answer. Ultimately only the grade can determine what one has learnt and knows as a result.